# Central extension: $Hom(Q,Z) \cong$ automorphisms of $G$ acting trivially on subgroup and quotient?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

If we have a short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow C \rightarrow G \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 1$ where $C$ is central in $G$ and $Q \cong G/C$, how can I find an isomorphism between $Hom(Q,C)$ (which is a group under pointwise multiplication) and the automorphisms of $G$ which act trivially on $C$ and $Q$?

I don't know any cohomology, so any hints from a more elementary perspective would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean ${\rm Hom}(Q,C)$? The homomorphism $\phi:Q \to C$ corresponds to the automorphism $g \mapsto g\phi(\tau(g))$, where $\tau:G \to Q$ is the given map.